# Android's ArrayAdapter: added fragments to rows work wrongly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am using ListView with ArrayAdapter and trying to add fragments to all rows of the ListView. However, the app does not work correctly: only one row on the screen showed with the added fragment but not all rows. Sometimes the app may be crashed because out of memory.

Can someone give me some advices? Thanks.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.me.test05;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
            myListView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdaptor(this, R.layout.row));
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private static final String[] allnames = { "John", "Marry", "Smith", "Felicity", "Lion", "Math" };

    public static class MyArrayAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;

        public MyArrayAdaptor(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return allnames.length * 100;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return allnames[position % allnames.length];
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            String str = getItem(position);
            textView.setText(str);

            FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.myFrameLayout, new PlaceholderFragment());
            ft.commit();

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

File activity.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/myListView" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:dividerHeight="2px">
    </ListView>

</merge>
```

File row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

File fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to display fragments? What is the list view supposed to do? I think you are making this harder than it should be.

Comment: Just for dealing with the complexity: in the next steps, my adding fragments may be more complexity and may be 10 different ones. Also, not only one but few fragments may be added to each row

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem. The problem is the fragment manager always find (to replace by a new fragment) an id in global. That is why it always found and added all new fragments into the first row since it is the first one contains that id (as well as all other rows).

To solve the problem, I create dynamic ids which are unique for each row then replace that fixed id by them before letting fragment manager to do the rest. I also store those dynamic ids into rows' tags to reuse latter.

The new code is bellow, including the code for finding and reusing added fragments:

```
package com.me.test05;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
            myListView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdaptor(this, R.layout.row));
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private View rootView = null;
        private String theString = null;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            setString(theString);

            return rootView;
        }

        public void setString(String str) {
            theString = str;
            if (theString != null && rootView != null) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                textView.setText(str);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final String[] allnames = { "John", "Marry", "Smith", "Felicity", "Lion", "Math" };

    public static class MyArrayAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;

        public MyArrayAdaptor(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return allnames.length * 100;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return allnames[position % allnames.length];
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = convertView;

            PlaceholderFragment myFragment = null;
            if (rowView == null) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                int newId = 100000 + position;
                FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myFrameLayout);
                layout.setId(newId);
                rowView.setTag(newId);

                myFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(newId, myFragment, "" + newId).commit();
            } else {
                Integer theId = (Integer) convertView.getTag();
                myFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(theId);
            }
            String str = getItem(position);
            myFragment.setString(str + ", " + position);

            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(str);

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```